# How to solve the \r (carriage return) problem that prevents Windows text files from being cross-platform with Linux?

Tags: c, linux, windows, cross-platform

**Intro**

There is a "feature" in Windows that adds a carriage return character before every newline. This is an old thing, but I am having trouble finding specific solutions to the problem.

**Problem**

If you create a file in Windows with `fopen("file.txt", "w")`, it will create a text file where every `\n` in your code is converted to `\r\n`. This creates a problem in situations where you try to read the file on Linux, because there is now an unaccounted-for character in the mix, and most line reads depend on reading to `\n`.

**Research**

I created text ("w") and binary ("wb") files on Windows and Linux, and tried to read and compare them with the same files made on the other OS.

Binary files do not get an added carriage return, and seem to work fine.

Text files, on the other hand, are a mixed bag:

- On Windows, comparing the Windows text file (`\r\n`) to the Linux text file (`\n`) will result in them being read equally (this is apparently a feature of some C Windows implementations - `\r\n` will get automatically read as `\n`)
- On Linux, comparing the files will result in them not being equal and the `\r` will not be handled, creating a reading problem.

**Conclusion**
I would like to know of ways how to handle this so my text files can be truly cross-platform. I have seen a lot of posts about this, but most have mixed and opposing claims and almost none have specific solutions.
So please, can we solve this problem once and for all after 40 years? Thank you.

Comment: No, we cannot solve this problem once and for all. If it were possible, it would have been done long ago. You simply cannot produce truly cross-platform text files. Different applications handle files in multiple ways, compare Editor/Notepad and Wordpad (both vanilla Microsoft) if they load a Unix/Linux text file.

Comment: Either you make room for `proprietary-standards` in your project or drop them for `open-standards`. Totally your call, whatever floats your boat.

Comment: Most text applications under windows can handle files with `\n` line ending. So forget that `\r\n` ever existed, and open your files in binary mode under windows. The only times you should use `\r\n`, is when using legacy data formats or protocols that explicitly demands it. But even then you should open files in binary mode and write `\r\n` explicitly. Remember that `\n` is a line terminator, and not line separator. That means that even the last line should be terminated by `\n`. The `\r\n` combo is often used as line separator which adds to the confusion.

Comment: Note also that some protocols require `\r\n` as the newline , such as HTTP headers, so not just Windows.

Comment: @HAL9000 wow man this actually sounds like a simple and valid solution. Congratulations. I may need to think about it to cover all positions, and definitely test it out, but this sounds like a solid solution. Save as text -> load as binary. PS: I just tested it out and win_bin == lnx_txt on Linux (lin_txt != win_txt ; lin_bin != win_txt ; lin_bin == win_bin). And on Windows every combination is equal. You should write an answer so you can get those updanks ;P

Comment: Nope, forget it. opening a text file with a `\r\n` in binary mode makes no difference as to the existence of the character. I ran the tests wrong.